# Will an epoll be woken up on EPOLLERR/EPOLLHUP if no other flags are provided?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, epoll, manpage

I want to add a file descriptor to an existing epoll instance but not have it wake up yet. Specifically, I would like to make sure that `EPOLLERR` and `EPOLLHUP` are not raised. I am using `EPOLLONESHOT` to wake up a single thread at a time, then `EPOLL_CTL_MOD` to re-arm once I'm done processing the events.

(My motivation is to use the same code path for handling a wakeup and creating a new socket: both of them could finish by calling `epoll_ctl` with `EPOLL_CTL_MOD` to re-arm the event. However, I don't want a spurious thread wakeup if an error occurs in the socket before the `EPOLL_CTL_MOD`).

According to the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html), that is not possible. Both `EPOLLERR` and `EPOLLHUP` claim that:

> epoll_wait(2) will always wait for this event; it is not necessary to set it in events when calling epoll_ctl().

However, after reviewing [eventpoll.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/eventpoll.c?h=v5.14-rc2&id=2734d6c1b1a089fb593ef6a23d4b70903526fe0c#n1146) in the Linux source tree, it looks like if no "public" `events` bits are set, the wakeup is suppressed. (Block comments in the original; line comments are my notes.)

```c
/* Epoll private bits inside the event mask */
#define EP_PRIVATE_BITS (EPOLLWAKEUP | EPOLLONESHOT | EPOLLET | EPOLLEXCLUSIVE)

// ...snip...

// Inside the callback function that fires on epoll wakeup:

    /*
     * If the event mask does not contain any poll(2) event, we consider the
     * descriptor to be disabled. This condition is likely the effect of the
     * EPOLLONESHOT bit that disables the descriptor when an event is received,
     * until the next EPOLL_CTL_MOD will be issued.
     */
    if (!(epi->event.events & ~EP_PRIVATE_BITS))
        goto out_unlock; // Exits the callback without waking userspace
```

Two concrete questions:

Is my reading of the kernel source correct that `EPOLLERR`/`EPOLLHUP` will not be triggered as long as no flags are specified apart from the four private bits?

Can I rely on this behavior that is undocumented in the man page?

Comment: "reviewing eventpoll.c in the Linux source tree" ..... not sure . "If the event mask does not contain any poll(2) event"  How about `POLLHUP`?   dragonfly bsd documentation may have something on that

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Thanks for the advice, but I don't think any of the BSDs support epoll. I am specifically looking for a Linux solution.

Comment: https://github.com/jiixyj/epoll-shim  has some docs.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, your use case would be: (1) a thread wakes up after an `epoll_wait()`, (2) creates a socket, (3) adds it to the existing epoll through `EPOLL_CTL_ADD`, (4) re-arms the epoll through `EPOLL_CTL_MOD` and (5) goes back to waiting. During this time, this thread is the only one interacting with the epoll. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Is my reading of the kernel source correct that EPOLLERR/EPOLLHUP will not be triggered as long as no flags are specified apart from the four private bits?

Insufficient information is provided to make that determination.

The C statement presented in the question tests whether `epi->event.events` has any bits set that are not set in `EP_PRIVATE_BITS`.  If not, then control branches to the statement labelled `out_unlock`.  It is not clear from the code presented whether following that branch means that neither `EPOLLERR` nor `EPOLLHUP` will be triggered.  And even if so, it also is not clear whether, when they are evaluated in that conditional, the contents of `epi->event.events` can be relied upon to be only the flags specified explicitly by the user.

> Can I rely on this behavior that is undocumented in the man page?

You can do whatever you want, but, generally speaking, relying on undocumented behavior is extremely unwise.  Relying on behavior contrary to documentation -- that is, on bugs -- is beyond unwise.

I am inclined to guess that something has escaped you in your source analysis, such that in fact the system produces epoll behavior that is consistent with the documentation.  But even if not, I really cannot imagine relying on a system interface to behave contrary to specification, unless in circumstances where you can actively ensure that the wanted behavior is realized.  And by "actively ensure" I mean take control of the implementation, not just study it.

Comment: I don't believe the behavior is "contrary to specification". `epoll_ctl(2)` reports for `EPOLLONESHOT`:  *Requests one-shot notification for the associated file descriptor. This means that after an event notified for the file descriptor by `epoll_wait(2)`, **the file descriptor is disabled in the interest list and no other events will be reported** by the epoll interface.* I would argue the only sensible way of making this work is to disable all events until re-arm. The kernel source code confirms this (that condition has been there since the introduction of `EPOLLONESHOT` in v2.6.2).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, whether the behavior is really contrary to spec is a valid question, but the OP asserts that the manpage excerpt presented says it is.

Comment: I'd say OP's interpretation of the manual page is simply wrong, not really their fault though as the manual page is poorly/misleadingly worded. `epoll(7)` also states: *"[...] specify the `EPOLLONESHOT` flag, to tell `epoll` to **disable the associated file descriptor** after the receipt of an event with `epoll_wait(2)`.  When the `EPOLLONESHOT` flag is specified, it is the caller's responsibility to rearm the file descriptor [...]"*.

Comment: I'm not relying on the OP's assertion, @MarcoBonelli.  The point is that if *they think* that a behavior is undocumented or, especially, contrary to documentation, then they have no business relying on that behavior.